# Proving a two part probability distribution is legitimate.

Tags: statistics

[image]
For this distribution, how do I prove that it is legitimate?

I think

1. I have to show that it is non-negative

and

2. I must show that it sums to one.

for 1) I think $\theta$ must be non negative but how do I show 2)?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}P[y_i = j] = \frac{(1-e^{-\theta})e^{-\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda}} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^j}{j!} \\ = \frac{(1-e^{-\theta})e^{-\lambda}}{1-e^{-\lambda}} (e^{\lambda}-1) = \frac{(1-e^{-\theta})(e^{\lambda}-1)}{e^{\lambda}-1} = 1-e^{-\theta}$$

Then:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}P[y_i = j] = P[y_i = 0] + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}P[y_i = j] = e^{-\theta} + 1-e^{-\theta} = 1$$

Comment: Thanks so much. How do I know that $${\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!} = (e^{- \lambda} - 1)$$